# I Cannot Use tf.keras.models.load_model() Function

Tags: tensorflow, pycharm, google-colaboratory, tf.keras

After training the pre-trained models I developed on Google Colab, I saved them and was trying to load the models in the PyCharm environment with the tf.keras.models.load_model() function to use them in the desktop application, but I was getting a warning that tensflow does not have a keras module. Also, I only get these errors when I use the keras.models.load_model() function;

- The error I get when I want to load the DenseNet121.keras model:

> ValueError: Layer 'conv1/conv' expected 1 variables, but received 0 variables during loading. Expected: ['conv1/conv/kernel:0']

- The error I get when I want to loadthe RegNetY008.keras model:

> ValueError: Layer 'regnety008_stem_conv' expected 1 variables, but received 0 variables during loading. Expected: ['regnety008_stem_conv/kernel:0']

- The error I get when I want to load the VGG19.keras model:

> ValueError: Layer 'block1_conv1' expected 2 variables, but received 0 variables during loading. Expected: ['block1_conv1/kernel:0', 'block1_conv1/bias:0']

As separate information, I accessed the versions of all the required libraries using the 'pip freeze > requirements.txt' command on Google Collab, and created an environment by installing these versions via Anconda Prompt, and used this environment as an interpreter in the PyCharm environment. I saved and downloaded the models I was trying to use with load_model to Google Drive.

I assumed that they were not downloaded properly and downloaded them again, but I got the same errors.

Additionally, when I transfer the models I have trained to the Google Colab environment via Gdrive, I can use them with the tf.keras.models.load_model() function and I do not receive any errors.

Models were saved with the model1.save('DenseNet121.keras') function in Tenseflow 2.15.0 and Keras 2.15.0.

Google Colab Code:

```
# DenseNet121 modelini yükleme
base_model1 = DenseNet121(weights='imagenet', include_top=False,
                          input_shape=(image_dimension, image_dimension, 3))

# Yeni bir model oluşturma
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(base_model1)
model1.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model1.add(Dropout(0.5))  # Dropout katmanı eklendi
model1.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Modeli derleme
optimizer1 = Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model1.compile(optimizer=optimizer1, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Modeli eğitme
history1 = model1.fit(train_set, epochs=epochs, validation_data=val_set)

model1.save('eski_model1_dense121.keras')

eski_model1_path= 'eski_model1_dense121.keras'
loaded_eski_model1_dense = tf.keras.models.load_model(eski_model1_path)
# Move the saved model to Google Drive
drive_model_filepath_eski_dense121 = '/content/drive/MyDrive/eski_model1_dense121.keras'
!cp '/content/eski_model1_dense121.keras' "$drive_model_filepath_eski_dense121"
```

PyCharm warning:
[image: warning]

I wanted to use the models I developed in the Google Colab environment in the PyCharm environment, but I could not load the models. How can I fix that?